# Kolab 3.3 Groupware Server on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install Kolab 3.3 on a Ubuntu 14.04 Server.
I am following those instructions  http://docs.kolab.org/installation-guide/ubuntu.html as well as described here https://monotok.org/install-kolab-mail-server-ubuntu/.

But still there is no way to install Kolab on Ubuntu 14.04. I get following errors when trying to execute

```
 sudo aptitude install kolab


 Errors were encountered while processing:
 clamav-base
 spamassassin
 php-kolabformat
 389-ds-base
 389-ds
 roundcubemail-plugins-kolab
 kolab-freebusy
 clamav-daemon
 irony
 kolab-mta
 chwala
 kolab-ldap
 kolab-syncroton
 kolab-conf
 kolab-webclient
 php-kolab
 sa-compile
 clamav-freshclam
 389-admin
 389-dsgw
 kolab
 389-ds-console
 389-admin-console
 clamav
```

What exactly is going wrong? **Do someone have any idea?** It would be so great to shed some light on this issue....

**Thanks to everyone!**